# Main Menu Navigation Item not linked to a content item but collapsing a sub menu

Tags: orchardcms

I have got a multi level navigation in **Orchard CMS** which shows sub menu items on hovering. When I click, it opens a content menu item. This works well on a PC but not on a mobile device. In case of a mobile device or touch device in general it should collapse the menu instead of jumping to another page.

I am looking for an easy and clean approach to solve this.

Is there a way to create such a menu item only acting as an opener for the sub menu items instead of actually linking to a page?

Some background information: It is actually a theme based on twittter bootstrap 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend the MenuItem shape (~/Core/Shapes/Views/MenuItem.cshtml) to differentiate between parent and children

So first create under {YourTheme}/Views new view called **MenuItem.cshtml** and paste in the following code

```
@{
    // odd formatting in this file is to cause more attractive results in the output.
    var items = Enumerable.Cast<dynamic>((System.Collections.IEnumerable)Model);
}
@{
    if (!HasText(Model.Text))
    {
        @DisplayChildren(Model)
    }
    else
    {
        if ((bool)Model.Selected)
        {
            Model.Classes.Add("current");
        }

        @* morphing the shape to keep Model untouched*@
        Model.Metadata.Alternates.Clear();
        if (items.Any())
        {
            Model.Classes.Add("dropdown");
            Model.Metadata.Type = "MenuItemLinkParent";
        }
        else
        {
             Model.Metadata.Type = "MenuItemLink";
        }

        @* render the menu item only if it has some content *@
        var renderedMenuItemLink = Display(Model);
        if (HasText(renderedMenuItemLink))
        {
            var tag = Tag(Model, "li");
            @tag.StartElement
            @renderedMenuItemLink

            if (items.Any())
            {
                <ul>
                    @DisplayChildren(Model)
                </ul>
            }

            @tag.EndElement
        }
    }
}
```

Now just create another view called **MenuItemLinkParent.cshtml** and create simple hyperlink placeholder that doesn't link anywhere

```
<a>@Model.Text</a>
```

Now any MenuItem which becomes parent will lose it's href link (you can also edit html structure and classes this way, if necessary for bootstrap). Easy and clean enough? :)

Comment: This is a very comprehensive description of a clean solution. But how to configure then the link in the backend? It seems to look a bit odd referencing a content item that is not really rendered as a link. I think there should really be a thing like "parent link" to create. Because it is confusing that you can actually define a link that gets not rendered in some cases.

Comment: Simplest is to just go to Admin > Navigation and create "Custom Link" with empty url and via drag & drop make your structure. Or if you want parent to be icon or something use "Html Menu Item".

Comment: When I leave the link empty it actually is a link on the "Index" page. The issue is that these link occur in the breadcrumb and are still clickable. Do you have a solution for this too?

Comment: Hmm guess this path is turning a bit troublesome for your scenario, if you have Orchard 1.7+ you can ditch the custom link and maybe even those new files I suggested and just use Shape Link for any parents. You can read about it here http://www.davidhayden.me/blog/shape-link-for-orchard-menus